# Loading output of System (char* command) to variable, c++

Tags: c++, linux, vector

...Am trying to load/capture the output of [system(char* command)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm) function to a variable, a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). can i have any possible way to push the output to my vector? I don*t want to write the output to file and read it again.
Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <string> dir;
    system("pwd");//here i used this to print the current directory, and i want to store this out put to my vector. something like...(below )
    output=output of system("pwd");//this is not a real code,just to notice i want to put the out put to other var and push.
    dir.push_back(output);
return 0;
}
```

Can i have any scenario to do this task, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`getcwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html)?

Comment: You can't get the output of the process executed by `system`. You can execute a command with `popen` to get a `FILE*` which you can read the output from.

Comment: hello: @BoPersson, thanks for your replay, but getcwd is used to capture the current working directory, that is a particular answer for my question. but what if i have other shell commands to be examined and executed by System() function. eg. system("Any command")?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing it like this:

```
FILE *fp = popen("fortune","r");
char line[200];
while(!feof(fp)) {
fgets(line,200,fp);
// process here
}
pclose(fp);
```

If it's really performance critical it's probably better to
create a child process using fork() and pipes for stdin/stdout of that child
process to write or read from.
An example of this could be found here (http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html#idp21888) if you're intested. But the popen method is probably the most simple and straightforward one in your case.